# What does "blow over someone's quest" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence

What do the following sentences intend to convey to the reader?

> - One blew over the industrialist's quest.
> - One blew over the ford's quest.

Comment: ford refers to the industrialist henry ford.

Comment: For future reference, proper names should be capitalized:  Henry Ford,  Ford's, etc., and are not preceded by *the* except when referring to a person's family as a whole, e.g., "The Fords were an interesting family"

Comment: Out of context, they convey absolutely nothing to me. I recognise that, as JoelBrown says, they are puns on the Ken Kesey title, and I can guess that "Ford" refers to Henry Ford. But I haven't the slightest idea what they are actually saying.

Answer (score 3):

This is very likely a (bad) pun intended to reference the book or film *One flew over the cuckoo's nest*. (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Flew_Over_the_Cuckoo%27s_Nest_%28film%29))

The intention would be to draw a parallel between the life or ambitions of Henry Ford or of industrialists generally (hard to say without more context) and the situation portrayed in the story.  It may simply be an ineffectual attempt to label Henry Ford a homicidal maniac, metaphorically speaking, by comparing Henry Ford to the character "Mac" from the story.

Comment: henry ford the industrialist was a visionary.

Comment: what about the lehman's ?

Comment: "One flew over the cuckoo's nest" was drawn by Kesey from a once very well known children's counting-out rhyme, which exists in many versions; a few are listed [*here*](http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question52475.html)

Comment: And in Kesey's book, *"the cuckoo's nest"* in the title clearly references the insane asylum where most of the book is set.

Comment: @RajeshKSingh - Henry Ford _was_ a visionary.  On the other hand he was a huge bigot, so you can't assume that everyone will be a big fan of the man.  Probably more to the point, there are people who like to disparage _all_ industrialists.  It's fashionable in some circles to criticize the people who built western society. I once had a professor that used to pine for the agrarian monastic lifestyle.  He didn't like me pointing out that if everyone lived an agrarian monastic lifestyle society wouldn't be able to afford universities, so he'd be out of a job.